# How to create an object dynamically from a string array?

Tags: java, c#, arrays, string, object

I have a String array in C# like below:

```
String[] myArray = {"1","Jack","18","2","John","22","3","Mark","29"}
```

Actually there are 3 objects in my array, first column is ID, second is Name and third is Age. So I need to insert 3 rows into my SQL table, each represents one person.

What is the best way to handle it?

I try:

```
Person p = new Person();
for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (i==0) p.Id = myArray[i];
    if (i==1) p.Name = myArray[i];
    if (i==2) p.Age = myArray[i];
    if (i%3==0) AddNewRecord(p);
}
```

But then how can I remove the first object from my array and start from 0 again?

Thanks.

PS. Couldn't find a proper title for my issue, sorry, appreciate if you may edit.

Edit: Java or C# answer, both fine by me

Comment: Looks like a homework help question, but the quickest (not cleanest) way to modify your code is to move the new Person() inside your loop, and instead of incrementing the array by one each time, increment it by `i += 3`, i.e. create your entire Person in one loop.

Comment: Since you are asking for best. Start with not using a Flat Array to store object data in memory.

Comment: @Ralf there are other restrictions, can't change the array type here

Comment: @C.Helling thanks for your suggestion. Still not sure how to go on after creating the first object tho.

Comment: @C.Helling Actually your suggestion is the **cleanest**, considering the input(i assume it can't be changed, since it looks like homework). Incrementing the index by one, as it is now, would require a very awkward initialization of each new person.

Answer (score 0):

You only take the first three values to create a Person object and then call `AddNewRecord` every 3rd iteration. Instead, every 3rd iteration you will need to set `p` to a new Person in order to prevent mutating the existing Person object already used to invoke `AddNewRecord`. To avoid only using the 3 first array elements, you want to % 3 on them too. 0 % 3 = 0, 1 % 3 = 1, 2 % 3 = 2, 3 % 3 = 0. Any number % 3 will tell you whether you're on the ID, Name or Age.

I think it's worth asking why you have an array of strings containing object data. Why not create the Person before putting all of their info in an array to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java solution.

You can use a `record` to hold the values.
Then, use a for-loop which increments by 3 on each iteration, to create a `List`.

```java
record Person(String id, String name, String age) { }
```

```java
List<Person> parse(String[] strings) {
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < strings.length; index += 3)
        list.add(new Person(strings[index], strings[index + 1], strings[index + 2]));
    return list;
}
```

Output

```java
[Person[id=1, name=Jack, age=18], Person[id=2, name=John, age=22], Person[id=3, name=Mark, age=29]]
```

Answer (score -2):

try below code this is worked you expected

```
for (int i = 0; i <= myArray.Length; i++)
{
if (i == 0) p.ID = myArray[i];
if (i == 1) p.Name = myArray[i];
if (i == 2) p.Age = myArray[i];
if (i!=0 && i % 2 == 0)
{
    if (myArray.Length > 0)
    {
        myArray = myArray.Skip(3).ToArray();
    }
    i = 0;
}
}
```